# Powershell: How to access iterated object in catch-block

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to simplify the situation as much as possible.

I have a set of files in that needs to be processed in a certain order because some of them are dependant on each other. But I don't have any reliable means to find out if a file has its dependencies fullfilled before processing it. - What i do have is an external function that throws an error if I try to process a file too early.
Thats why I'm trying to iterate though those files until all of them have been processed.

(those files contain so called "extensions" if you wonder about the variable names.)

What I'm trying to do is, catching the Files that are not able to get published to the server, yet in the "catch" area and start the while loop over with the remaining set until all files are processed or the script reached its deadloop limiter of 20 loops.

```
$path = 'C:\abcd'
  
$ExtList = (Get-ChildItem $path -Filter '*.app' -Recurse).FullName

$i = 0 #stop deadloop

while (($ExtList.Count -gt 0) -and ($i -lt 20)) {
    $i++
    [array]$global:FailedExt = @()
    [array]$global:FailedExtError = @()

    $ExtList | % {
        try {
            Publish-Extension -Path $_ 
        } catch {
            $global:FailedExt += $_
            $global:FailedExtError += $Error[0]
        }
    }

    #Set ExtList to list of remaining Extensions
    $ExtList = $global:FailedExt
}

if ($global:FailedExt.Count -gt 0) { #dependencies weren't the Problem
    $ErrorMsg = "Could not publish the following Extensions:`n`n"
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $FailedExt.Count; $i++) {
        $ErrorMsg += "Error in: " + ($global:FailedExt[$i]) + ":`n"
        $ErrorMsg += " - Error: " + ($global:FailedExtError[$i]) + "`n`n"
    }
    throw $ErrorMsg
}
```

MY Problem:
Apparently the value of `$_` in the catch-block isn't the same as in the try-block because i get
This error output:

```
Could not publish the following Extensions:

Error in: Cannot bind parameter 'Path' to the target. Exception setting "Path": "Illegal characters in path.":
 - Error: Cannot bind parameter 'Path' to the target. Exception setting "Path": "Illegal characters in path."

Error in: Cannot bind parameter 'Path' to the target. Exception setting "Path": "Illegal characters in path.":
 - Error: Cannot bind parameter 'Path' to the target. Exception setting "Path": "Illegal characters in path."

Error in: Cannot bind parameter 'Path' to the target. Exception setting "Path": "Illegal characters in path.":
 - Error: Cannot bind parameter 'Path' to the target. Exception setting "Path": "Illegal characters in path."
```

And then, on the second iteration, the script tries to use the Error-Message as a Path to the file I'm trying to publish. - Which results in a set of "illegal characters in path"-Messages.

p.s. If you know any other improvements to my code, let me know (I'm new to PS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a `catch` block, the `$_` automatic variable refers to the [current error record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally#accessing-exception-information), so it hides the `$_` variable that refers to the current item processed by `ForEach-Object` (alias `%`).

You may use a [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach) statement to control the name of the loop variable:

```
foreach( $CurrentPath in $ExtList ) {
    try {
        Publish-Extension -Path $CurrentPath 
    } catch {
        $global:FailedExt += $CurrentPath
        $global:FailedExtError += $_    # Add current error record
    }
}
```

Note I also replaced `$Error[0]` by `$_` which is the idiomatic way to access error information in a `catch` block.

---

A (less readable) way that works with `ForEach-Object` is to use the automatic variable [`$input`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables#input), which refers to the current pipeline object of a `process {}` block (actually it is a single-element array [as discovered by mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71116115/powershell-how-to-access-iterated-object-in-catch-block/71116314?noredirect=1#comment125714501_71116314)). This works here because the script block passed to `ForEach-Object` runs in the `process {}` block by default (unless you use parameter `-begin` or `-end`).

```
$ExtList | % {
    try {
        Publish-Extension -Path $_ 
    } catch {
        $global:FailedExt += $Input    # Add current ForEach-Object item
        $global:FailedExtError += $_   # Add current error record
    }
}
```

Without the comment the code isn't self-explanatory as the `$input` variable is rarely used. If you really have to stick with `ForEach-Object`, I recommend to assign `$_` to another variable, as explained by [Joel Coehoorn's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71116293/7571258).

---

Just for *educational* purposes I tried to find another way using [`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable) with parameter `-Scope`, which allows you to get a variable of the same name from a [parent scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes#parent-and-child-scopes). As `catch` doesn't create a new child scope, we have to artificially create a child scope using a script block (`& {}`):

```
$ExtList | % {
    & {         # A script block starts a new child scope
        try {
            Publish-Extension -Path $_ 
        } catch {
            # Get the $_ variable from the parent scope (the loop)
            $global:FailedExt += Get-Variable _ -Scope 1 -ValueOnly
            $global:FailedExtError += $_   # Add current error record
        }
    }           
}
```

While this works, I don't recommend to use this technique. Compared to the first solution, the code looks almost obfuscated and is very hard to follow.

Comment: @mklement0 I've added another workaround using `$Input`. You propably agree that it isn't very readable. Anyway, you need to know your options before decidedly discard them. ;-)

Comment: :) Intriguing. `$input` is normally an _enumerator_, but inside a `ForEach-Object` script block it apparently surfaces as a _single-element array_ containing the current pipeline item: `'a', 'b', 'c' | % { $Input.GetType().Name }`

Comment: @mklement0 In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#input) it says "contains the object that is currently in the pipeline". Didn't expect a single-element array!

Comment: @mklement0 In the `process{}` block of a script cmdlet, `$input` is a single-element `ArrayList` instead: https://code.labstack.com/zWQXzcks

Answer (score 3):

Fwiw, I'm curious to know the same thing: if there's a way to avoid the `$_` replacement or preserve or access the prior value in the exception context.

That said, I do know you can work around it by assigning `$_` to a new variable as the first line of the loop:

```sh
$ExtList | % {
    try {
        $loopItem = $_
        Publish-Extension -Path $loopItem 
    } catch {
        # $_ is the exception, $loopItem is still good
        $global:FailedExt += $loopItem
        $global:FailedExtError += $Error[0]
    }
}
```

Comment: `$ExtList | % -PipelineVariable foo { try { / * ... */ } catch { Write-Host $foo } }`

Comment: @Tomalak Doesn't work, because `-PipelineVariable` defines the name of the output variable. It is only usable by the next pipeline command. Try `1..2 | % -PV foo { $foo }` and then try `1..2 | % -PV foo { $_ } | % { $foo }`.

Comment: @zett42 Oh... That's inconvenient. Damn. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: @Tomalak I still learned something, so a net win today ;)